# Why does linq not implement full-laziness?

Tags: c#, linq

I have following code, I thought that it will work:

```
static int ComputerFailsOnTrue(bool flag)
{
    if (flag)
        throw new Exception();  
    return 10; // not relevant
}

static IEnumerable<double> StartComputer()
{
    yield return ComputerFailsOnTrue(true);
    yield return ComputerFailsOnTrue(false);
    yield return ComputerFailsOnTrue(false);
}

static public void Main()
{
    foreach (var item in StartComputer().Skip(1))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hey {item}");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But it fails(i'll get the exception), because first element of collection will be computed. Why does `moveNext` method of enumerator from given collection always compute current element?
Is it assumption, that computation of current can be dependant of previous state?

Comment: Devs were lazy to go full lazy

Comment: Yes, it is assumption, that computation of current can be dependent on previous state.

Comment: What is the expected output? And what output do you get? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: To do what you expected, there'd have to be a way to mark *parts* of the generator method as the parts that need to execute for `MoveNext` and separately the parts that compute `Current`, and for the latter set of parts to be delayed until accessed. I don't have a clear idea what that would look like and it would also be complete overkill for most generators. Also, of course, you're not *forced* to use a generator - you're allowed to write your own implementation of `IEnumerable` which has the laziness you desire.

Comment: @YacoubMassad, I thought that first element of collection will not be computed

Comment: For such lazy person lazy MS has solution which is called exactly lazy. :-)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - he expects that foo().Skip(1) would not actually compute foo() - and instead defer execution until Skip(1) is executed, which should skip that `null` element.

Comment: It seems that this has nothing to do with it "not being lazy" and everything to do with the fact that `Skip` *still has to enumerate the collection*. The exception above is thrown as part of that enumeration (as opposed to say skipping through `n` items of an `IEnumerable<Func<bool, int>>` and then executing from there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a failing of LINQ, per se. It's an issue related to two things - the [`IEnumerator<T>` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb(v=vs.110).aspx) and C#'s [iterator methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt639331.aspx).

`IEnumerator<T>` only has two interesting members - `MoveNext` and `Current`. The only way to implement `Skip` atop such an interface<sup>1</sup> is to call `MoveNext` as many times as the number of items you wish to skip, and of course, any implementation of `MoveNext` is free to run arbitrary code on each method call. What it can do is avoid accessing `Current`.

In C#'s implementation of iterators, which "automatically" generate implementations of `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>`, the `MoveNext` and `Current` are intimately linked - you only write one method, and each time that method gains control (for a `MoveNext`), it also has to compute the next `Current` value.

If you were implementing `IEnumerator<T>` by hand, you would be free to place *some* logic in your `MoveNext` method and *some* logic within your `Current` property, including making the evaluation of `Current` lazy. In such an implementation, if the call to `compute(true)` was part of your implementation of `Current`, your code would work as you had expected.

---

<sup>1</sup>There may be some specializations within LINQ which bypasses using the enumerator for built-in collection classes, but in general, this is the interface that is used.

Answer (score 3):

It is still lazy, it's just that when you enumerate it, you will enumerate the result of skip `Skip(1)` with need to call `MoveNext` twice, and that runs the compiler generated state machine that the `foo` method produces, and that throws an exception.

The exception isn't a result of evaluating the current item, all of the code in the method gets incrementally executed as you enumerate it.

If you called `var a = foo().Skip(1)` no exception would be thrown.

Comment: I don't understand you. Why is it lazy? MoveNext forces to compute current value. Computation of first element throws exception

Comment: @LmTinyToon please see my updated answer. You are executing all of the code in the method incrementally. There is no "computation of element".

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that you misread deferred and lazy concepts. It is two different concepts, though they could be mixed if needed.

```
static int ComputerFailsOnTrue(bool flag)
{
    if (flag)
        throw null;
    return 10;
}
static IEnumerable<Lazy<double>> foo()
{
    yield return new Lazy<double>(()=>ComputerFailsOnTrue(true));
    yield return new Lazy<double>(()=>ComputerFailsOnTrue(false));
    yield return new Lazy<double>(()=>ComputerFailsOnTrue(false));
}
static public void Main()
{
    foreach (var item in foo().Skip(1).Select(l=>l.Value))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Hey {item}");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```